# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_WKUserScript...Expected in ...WebKit

Tags: ios, xcode

I have `Xcode 7.3.1` trying to run an app which supports from `iOS 7` but failed, it crashes on the splash screen and console gives:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_WKUserScript
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/...AppPath...
Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
in ...AppPath...
(lldb)
```

I checked the package content and my Xcode 7.3.1 has the iOS 6, 7, 8, 9, 10's device disk images.

And the same app can be running normally on iOS 8, 9, 10 device by this Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WKUserScript, and WebKit in general, is only available starting with iOS8. The frameworks the linker links are different from version to version. On iOS7 there is no WK framework, this WKUserScript.

If you really need support for iOS7 you will have to conditionally compile and use UIWebView on iOS7 handling gracefully the unavailable functionality. (Yay, tons of work probably)